# Writing class with start and shutdown

Tags: java

I have a class that represents an external resource (could be a thread or file etc.) This class has `start` and `shutdown` methods (`start` starts the thread and `shutdown` closes the thread for example). The class also exposes several methods: `method_1`, `method_2`,..., `method_n` that act on the external resource.

The problem with this design is that is is only valid to call one of the `methods` between a call to `start` and `shutdown`. Because of this I have to add boilerplate of `if (!started()) throw new IllegalStateException()` to all `n` `methods`. This also forces a user to be careful to guard all calls to the `methods` with `if (resource.started()) resource.method();`

We can guarantee the `start` is called by making the constructor private and adding a static factory method `createStarted()` which will return `null` if `start` fails. The problem still persists however, because a user can still call `shutdown()` and then call a `method`. So we still need to guard all the `methods`.

This feels like a waste to have to add this boilerplate to all `methods` to protect against improper use of the class. Ideally, I would like a way for the compiler to enforce this restraint (like we did with `start`) instead of having it enforced at runtime.

**Failed solution attempts**

1. Have `shutdown` return a `NoOpResource` which extends all functions in `Resource` to `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();` This doesn't solve the boilerplate problem because you still need to remember to extend all `n` `methods`.
2. Ignore the problem and have the users live at their own peril. If a user call `shutdown` and then another method, they deserve to be in the undefined state that they got themselves into. This seems a bit dangerous and I think I would prefer the boilerplate over this.

Comment: This seems similar to how some `java.io` classes cause an IDE to be able to throw warning if a method is called after `.close()` is called on that resource.  This may be something built into the IDE though and not part of the class. Not sure

Comment: You want something like: `try (Resource.Access a = new Resource.Access(resource)) { ... }` and let `Access` wrap the resource. To use try-with-resources let `Resource.Access` implement `AutoClosable`.

Comment: BeyelerStudios@ Yes, that's the correct usage of the class. But I can't enforce this usage AFAIK. A misguided user would still be able to use the class improperly by forgetting to try with resources.

Comment: Then go for option 2: don't write libraries for fools, instead promote good coding conventions. Also if the IDE is good enough, the fact that you implement `AutoCloseable` can be used by it to warn about any misuse of this specific concept.

Comment: Is there any way to get a compiler to warn about usage after close, some annotation on close perhaps?

Comment: The documentation of `AutoCloseable` is strict enough for any IDE to warn about such misuse (emphasis mine): *A resource that **must be closed** when it is no longer needed.* and for `close`: *Closes this resource, **relinquishing any underlying resources**.* ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html))

Comment: Why does client code have to call `start()` explicitly? Couldn't the first invocation of `method_i` start the resource if it hadn't already been started? I think `AutoCloseable` works well for the shutdown part.

Comment: BeyelerStudios@, at least for eclipse 4.6.2 there is no warning for using an `AutoCloseable` after `close` is called (at least with my settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resolve this with additional "manager" class. What i encountered some time ago was similar problem to yours. I used flightweight pattern which stored my objects, if you will use just one class at the time, or you can't get those class from flyweight (because there is no key that can make difference between two instances of your class) you can make one "adapter manager". I think about something like this:

```
public class YourClass {

    CustomClosableAction doOnClose;

    public YourClass(CustomClosableAction doOnClose) {
        this.doOnClose = doOnClose;
    }

    public void initialize() {
    }

    public void shutDown() {
        doOnClose.onClosing();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface CustomClosableAction {
        void onClosing();
    }

}


public final class YourClassFactory {

    private YourClass instance = null;

    public YourClass getYourClass() {
        YourClass.CustomClosableAction onClosing = () -> {
            instance = null;
        };

        if(instance == null) {
            YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(onClosing);
            yourClass.initialize();
        }

        return instance;
    }

}
```

Now if someone will want to obtain your class he will get it from YourClassFactory, because you are creating the doOnClose action, as set the instance to null, if someone will shutDown your class it will be removed from YourClass factory, then if someone will invoke getYourClass it will create and initialize new instance.

And here is variation number Two, you can expose only "manager" class as Adapter and then get your user something like this:

```
public final class YourClassAdapter implements AutoCloseable {

    private YourClass instance = null;

    public YourClassAdapter(){

    }

    private YourClass getYourClass() {
        YourClass.CustomClosableAction onClosing = () -> {
            instance = null;
        };

        if(instance == null) {
            YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(onClosing);
            yourClass.initialize();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void yourClassMethodOne(){
        getYourClass().yourClassMethodOne();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        getYourClass().shutDown();
    }
}
```

Then you will always work on resources, even after shutdown, if client will invoke method it will reinitialize your class and then do this method. This can prevent users from using your class wrong and it will be invoked without exceptions, but you must be sure, that you can always work on resources, even after they are closed.

This is only my idea to show you how you can make your class user safe, but if you cannot reinitialize your class, and after shutdown it should be garbage collected better throw exception, or rethink my first example. I hope that this is understandable.

Comment: Thanks, I think this just adds a level of indirection without solving the problem. I can still write: `YourClass yc = adapter.getYourClass(); adapter.close(); yc.doSomething();`

Comment: That is why in second example getYourClass is private and invoked only by methods. You can make your class visible only to YourClassAdapter, and then user will work only on Adapter

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating an aspect with AspectJ? It could look something like this, which would be invoked before any method in your `MyResource` class.

```
@Aspect
public class ResourceAspect {

  @Before("execution(* com.example.MyResource.*) ")
  public void beforeResourceMethod(JoinPoint jp) {
    MyResource r = (MyResource) jp.getThis();
    if(!r.isStarted()) throw new IllegalStateException();
  }

}
```

It is possible to use AspectJ with Spring AOP, or AspectJ by itself.

Comment: Interesting, I had never heard of AOP I'll read more about it.

Comment: I am pretty sure my exact code won't work, but it shows the basic idea. From my experience, getting aspects to work is a bit painful due to the syntax and what I consider unhelpful error/debug messages. But once it gets working its very useful and can save you a ton of code, especially when it comes to logging.

Comment: After reading a bit this appears to be a very risky paradigm (passing judgment from atop Mount Wikipedia) and I'm not sure I want to introduce it into my code.